# Learning stats with mathematica

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, math-software

Having just completed my Bachelor with a major in math and physics, I am aware that due to my chosen specialisation, I lack a good training and exposure in statistic beyond the first year.

Could anyone recommend a good book on statistic where the author uses Wolfram Mathematica as a computational tool?

Comment: It would be better to ask the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you and I will do so.

Comment: See:  http://www.mathstatica.com/book/   A free download of the original PDF version of the book is available at: http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html